# Embed $\mathbb{P}^1$ with $n$ marked points in $\mathbb{P}^{n-2}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

I read (see Inv. to Quantum Coh. by Vainsencher, p. 40) that

> A $\mathbb{P}^1$ with $n$ marked points $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ is embedded in $\mathbb{P}^{n-2}$ by
> the linear system $|K_{\mathbb{P}^1} + P_1 + \ldots + P_n| = |\mathcal{O}(n-2)|$.

What is the embedding, explicitly?

Comment: Are you sure about your indicies? $\Bbb P^r$ has $r+1$ coordinate points.

Comment: @KReiser It is stated as such in the book.

Comment: @KReiser What would you propose otherwise?

Comment: Maybe I was hasty in my objection - it depends on what one means when one says "coordinate points". My interpretation was the points $[1:0:\cdots:0],\cdots,[0:\cdots:0:1]$, of which there are $r+1$ in $\Bbb P^r$. Perhaps the book uses the term differently? (I do not have a copy.)

Comment: @KReiser Aah, that's where the confusion is. The book also considers $[1:\ldots:1]$ to be a coordinate point. Therefore, according to the books convention there are $r+2$ coordinate points in $\mathbb{P}^r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$t \mapsto \bigg[ \frac{p_n - p_1}{t - p_1} : \frac{p_n - p_2}{t - p_2} : \cdots :  \frac{p_n - p_{n-1}}{t - p_{n-1}} \bigg]$$

Comment: What in this map is $t$? Would $t = \infty$ be a possibility? If so, what is the meaning of $ t - p_k$?

Comment: $t \in \mathbb{P}^1$, $\infty \mapsto [p_n - p_1 : \cdots : p_n - p_{n-1}]$ (rescale the homogeneous coordinates by $t$ and take $t \to \infty$.)